# Synchronise sql server changes between databases

Tags: sql-server

What is the best/easiest way to replicate the changes in one databases to another database?

I say replicate, because the changes may just be one way. However, in some cases there may need to be changes going both ways so also 2 way sync.

This is for a work environment so free or cheap and easy-to-implement solutions are best. Diff has been mentioned, how would this work? (On the database's create script)? What other wwy is there?

Thanks

Comment: Redgate SQL Compare suite. Not free but worth the money in overall time savings - especially for a work environment (comment rather than answer because this is a duplicate many times over just can't be bothered to look for one now)

Comment: SQL Server Replication or RedGate: take your pick (Or Backup / Restore )

Comment: 704 questions, 95 upvotes cast seems a little on the low side...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I [blogged about this a while back](http://www.onetooneglobal.com/otocorporate-posts/2009/06/01/the-cost-of-reinventing-the-wheel/), mentioning a long list of schema comparison tools - several of them very cheap or free. The thrust of the post, though, is that you get what you pay for: just spending the money on a tool that you know will work is much more cost effective than wasting time on tools that might not (or writing your own solution). I highly recommend you give [Red-Gate SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/) a trial, as well as a few of the free ones, and you can compare for yourself whether it's worth the money.